# ¿Cúal es la utilidad de tener un argumento por separado en una función en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, es6

El ejemplo más sencillo para plantearlo mejor es con una función flecha `suma`

```js
const suma = ({a, b}, c) =>  a + b + c;
    
    console.log(suma({ a:10, b:17}, 100)); // 127
```

o ¿De qué manera funciona un argumento por separado?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Es importante mencionar que no hay ningún argumento por separado, se están pasando 2 argumentos a la función:

- El primero será un objeto (especificado por `{ a, b }`)
- El segundo será una variable (que se llamará `c`)

Y entonces se está haciendo [asignacion por destructuración](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Destructuring_assignment). Esto es una expresión de JavaScript (también presente en otros lenguajes como Python o Perl) que permite la extracción de datos usando una sintaxis que equivale a la construcción de arreglos y objetos.

En este caso, se le está diciendo a la función que el primer parámetro va a ser un objeto que va a tener las propiedades `a` y `b`, y que lo desestructure para usar las variables `a` y `b` equivalentes a esas propiedades `a` y `b` del objeto.

Pero una ejemplo vale más que mil palabras. El código que tienes ahora mismo para `suma`:

```
const suma = ({a, b}, c) =>  a + b + c;
```

equivaldría (más o menos) a hacer lo siguiente sin notación de flecha y sin destructuración:

```
const suma = function(obj, c) {
  var a = obj.a;
  var b = obj.b;
  var c = c;
  return a + b + c;
}
```

Puedes ver ambos métodos comparados aquí:

```js
const suma = ({a, b}, c) =>  a + b + c;   
console.log(suma({ a:10, b:17}, 100)); // 127

const suma2 = function(obj, c) {
  var a = obj.a;
  var b = obj.b;
  var c = c;
  return a + b + c;
}
console.log(suma2({ a:10, b:17}, 100)); // 127
```

---

Como nota, es importante indicar que los nombres de las propiedades usadas deben existir en el objeto o se producirán errores. Por ejemplo, este código fallará porque el objeto no tiene propiedad `b` (sólo `a` y `d`):

```js
const suma = ({a, b}, c) =>  a + b + c;   
console.log(suma({ a:10, d:17}, 100)); // NaN porque b no existe
```

Y eso también funciona "al revés": se puede pasar un objeto con más propiedades y luego sólo usar unas pocas de ellas. En el siguiente ejemplo puedes ver como se le pasa un objeto a `suma` que tiene las propiedades `a`,  `b` y `d`, pero sólo vamos a usar `a` y `b` que son las que se indican en el parámetro de la función flecha:

```js
const suma = ({a, b}, c) =>  a + b + c;   
console.log(suma({ a:10, b:17, d:10}, 100)); // 127 (d se ignora)
```

Comment: Gracias por la información Alvaro!

Comment: Excelente respuesta, de forma muy clara, gracias por el dato amigo!

Answer (score 4):

> ¿Cúal es la utilidad de tener un argumento por separado en una función
>   en JavaScript?

Depende como requieras el método reciba los datos, en el caso que muestras, el segundo argumento es un valor que no es recibido como objeto en la función,

> ¿De qué manera funciona un argumento por separado?

La función obtiene los 2 valores del objeto (`{a, b}`) los cuales suma entre si (`a + b`) y estos a su vez los suma con el segundo valor que recibe la función (`c`):

```js
const suma = ({a, b}, c) =>  a + b + c;

console.log(suma({ a:10, b:17}, 100)); // 127
```

Puedes no usar un segundo argumento y agregar el valor del segundo argumento al `objeto`, en este caso se obtienen los valores del `objeto` y se suman, tu función recibiría solo un argumento:

```js
const suma2 = ({a, b, c}) =>  a + b + c;

console.log(suma2({ a:10, b:17, c:100})); // 127
```